# What is the correct way of pad and reshape a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Given the following tensor:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(59,), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])>
```

What is the correct way of reshape it and pad it into `(32, 59)`? From keras docs I tried to:

`keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(t, 32)`

Nevertheles I am getting:

```
ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

Also, I tried:

```
tf.reshape(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(a[0]).padded_batch(32), [32,59])
```

However, I am getting:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PaddedBatchDataset shapes: (None, 59), types: tf.int64>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PaddedBatchDataset'>) to a Tensor.
```

What is the correct way of doing a 32 padding and reshape it into `32,59`?

Comment: You can just repeat the `( 59 , )` 32 times to produce an array `( 32 , 59 )`. Use `tf.repeat()`

Comment: Could you provide an example? @ShubhamPanchal thanks

Comment: Would it solve your issue? This won't be similar to padding.

Comment: It would be better if I padd it and reshape it @ShubhamPanchal

Comment: See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're useing `tf.keras` `tf.pad` should be preferred choice for tensor padding ([see docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)).

From what it looks like you have tensor of shape `(59, )` and want to pad the tensor to shape `(32, 59)`. This would be done as

```py
# 15 rows before, 16 rows after, 0 cols before and after
paddings = tf.constant([[15, 16], [0, 0]])
# first reshape tensor to (1, 59), then pad it
padded = tf.pad(tensor[tf.newaxis, ...], paddings)
```

default padding is with zeros, see the docs for other options.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What about if I have arbitray size tensors, and I want to reshape all of them into `(32, n)`, where `n` is the original shape?

Comment: I tried: `x2=tf.reshape(x, [59,1])
paddings = tf.constant([[15, 16], [0, 0]])
tf.pad(x2, paddings)`, and I ended up with a tensor `shape=(90, 1)`

Comment: do you want the result to be `(32, 59)` or `(59, 32)`? you want to pad along the dimension you add, for your example, the padding should be `tf.constant([[0, 0], [15, 16]])` because you added 1st dimension instead of 0th dimension as I did in the answer. Regarding your earlier question, is `n` a scalar? if so, the answer should work. If we are talking about `n` dimensional tensor it's just a matter of cleverly constructing the `paddings` tensor, I can try to think of something but the scenario when I don't know the dimensions of a tensor I pad seems weird to me.